# Find IDs of all edges between vertexes with igraph Python

Tags: python, igraph

With the Python igraph library, I have a directed graph representing a road network, with distance between each vertex (coordinates) as the weight. It is quite possible that there can be two or more edges between a vertex pair, with different weights. I need to retrieve these weights from the graph by querying the vertex IDs e.g. an example graph:

```
import igraph as ig

g = ig.Graph(directed=True)

g.add_vertices(4)

edges = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
g.add_edges(edges)

g.es[:]["dist"] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I know I can get the id of an edge, and then the attributes as follows, but this only seems to find the last added e.g:

```
g.get_eid((0, 1)) # returns 0
g.get_eid((1, 2)) # returns 2
```

So, there are two edges between 1 and 2, but only one is returned by get_eid - I need to know both to then query the edge attributes and return the weightings, to select the correct minimum distances from the graph, as were used by a distance-weighted shortest path query. Is there a way to do this with igraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are out of luck with python. The documentation for `get_eid` says

> Returns the edge ID of an arbitrary edge between vertices v1 andv2

The documentation for `get_eids` says explicitly:

> The method does not consider multiple edges; if there are multiple edges 
>   between a pair of vertices, only the ID of one of the edges is returned.

Oddly, the R version of igraph *does* support the functionality that you want. 
The function `get.edge.ids` has an argument `multi` that allows you to get multiple edges like this.

In desperation, I tried adding `multi=True` to the python code, but it simply gave me:

> 'multi' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: That was my conclusion too, and also saw the R implementation differs. Too bad. So, I'll just record the relevant data in a dict, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

further to @G5W's answer, the `get_eid` function seems to be giving not an "arbitrary" edge between two nodes but, in case of multiple nodes, the one with the highest id. consider:

```
g = ig.Graph()
g.add_vertices(['A', 'B', 'C'])
g.add_edges([('A', 'B'), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'C')])
g.get_eid(0, 1) #always returns 2
g.get_eid(1, 2) #always returns 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select` method to get `EdgeSeq` of all edges between two vertices:

```
g.es.select(_source=0, _target=1)
```